# Erro no import de arquivos js (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, chatbot

Estou começando a aprender algumas coisas de node e para isso estou criando um chatbot usando o Blip. Mas quero fazer isso com um js externo, realizando a conexão. Porem estou tendo um problema ao tentar rodar minha apicação node. Vou deixar um print abaixo para ficar mais claro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso nao fique claro na foto, esse é o erro:

```
PS C:\Testes\Take_chatbot> node index
C:\Testes\Take_chatbot\index.js:1

import * as BlipSdk from 'blip-sdk';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
PS C:\Testes\Take_chatbot>
```

Pelo meu entendimento o js nao está encontrando os dois arquivos que listei nos imports, mas como posso resolver este erro? Estas pastas realmente existem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar do operador `import` estar definido na sintaxe do JavaScript, o motor do NodeJS, V8, ainda não implementa esse operador.

Para importar o módulo, você terá que utilizar a função `require` da seguinte maneira:

```
const BlipSdk = require('blip-sdk');
```

É possível usar o operador `import` se você utilizar um compilador que converta sintaxe moderna para uma compatível com o NodeJS, como o `Babel`.

Babel é utilizado principalmente para converter código que utiliza funcionalidades mais recentes, em código compatível com navegadores antigos. Mas se o seu código está rodando apenas no seu computador, pode ser que não haja tanta motivação para utilizar essa ferramenta.

Comment: Ótima explicação. Entendi e funcionou perfeitamente no meu código. Obrigado @user140828